# Move (Copy) SQL Server 2017 table to a local database in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization, localdb, sql-server-2017

I developed a C# (Visual Studio 2017, Windows Forms applications) project. I used SQL Server 2017 for database operations, my database table has 3 columns and 200000 rows. I will run the project on other computers. Users will not do any SQL operation, you can think of as readonly.

Some mathematical operations will be performed according to the values ​​selected from Listbox and the results will be displayed on the DataGridView. So you can think of seeing an analysis result. They will not perform operations such as adding, deleting, updating. Look at the results of the analysis and close the program. And these values ​​will not need to intervene later, the constant values ​​that will never change. For this I want to copy the same table in the database to the locale. I'm new at this, it's my first project in full detail.

Does anybody know how I'm gonna do that? I want to understand in detail.

Thank you.

Comment: Just write all the data to a JSON or XML file and include this file with your app. Read the file into a List<> when it starts up and use this collection instead of the SQL selects you had before. You can use LINQ instead of SQL for the queries. Either that or look into using SQL LocalDB which is a lightweight version of SQL Server that is quite portable.

Comment: @Jon which version of SQL LocalDB should I use?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017#install-localdb  whatever is the latest version

Comment: @Jon I did it, it works. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Jon Hi again sir. I installed SQL Server Expression LocalDB 2017 and i moved my database in it. I connected my new database to my project. And it's extension is .mdf. Does this provide my requirement (I mean; can I run it with only the project setup without having any installation on other users' computers?). My connection string is; "Data Source=(localdb)\MyInstance;AttachDbFilename=C:\...\databasename.mdf;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True". And should I change my connection string for run my project on other users' computers?

Comment: I believe you need to deploy the SqlLocalDb.msi file with your app, the runtime needs to be installed but it’s a quick install. You can roll it into the setup msi file of your app setup project. I know it’s a pain but I believe you need it. Would be easy enough to test on a blank Windows VM?

Comment: @Jon Let me test it. I'll tell you again here sir.

Comment: If you want to avoid the database install, I think the idea of pulling into memory from a file on startup was a good one. Unless you've got really wide columns, 200k rows may not be a huge memory hog. Iterating an in-memory list object would probably be better performance than even querying a local SQL Express db. That still has to read from disk first. By putting it in memory on startup you avoid that cost and delay. It might be unnoticeable though, you'll have to test! :)